# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it in Mysql Work bench?

Tags: php, sql, database

I have created php and Mysql site.Its Working Locally Xampp well. Finally I moved My site to server..i have Used Mysql Workbench. connected client database in Mysql Workbench in My system.when I Run the code its showing Error:

> Validating Information....error with query: SELECT ID,fname,lname,email,userlevel,user_group,orgID FROM students WHERE username='test' AND password='123456' No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

```
<?php

class db

{

    var $persistent=0;

    var $query;



    var $user="abaceu";

    var $pass ="******";

    var $host="*********";

    var $mydb="mysql_24172_abacu";  

    var $rlink;



    function connect()

    {

        if($this->persistent==1)

        {

        $this->rlink = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass);

        }

        else

        {

        $this->rlink = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass);

        }

  mysql_select_db ($this->mydb);




  }





    function query($SQL)

    {

    $this->query=mysql_query($SQL)or die( "error with query: $SQL ".mysql_error() );

    }



    function getRows()

    {

    $this->moreRows=mysql_fetch_array($this->query);



        if($this->moreRows<1)

        {

        @mysql_close($this->rlink);

        }



    return $this->moreRows;

    }



    function row($column)

    {

    return $this->moreRows[$column];

    }

    function close()

    {

        @mysql_close($this->rlink);

    }



}





/*

$db = new db;

$db->connect();

$db->query("SELECT * FROM x_groups");

//$db->query("INSERT INTO x_groups (group_ID,name) VALUES ('mm10','mystery tester 10')");



while($db->getRows())

//while(odbc_fetch_into($rlink, $row));

{ 

echo $db->row("name")."---".$db->row("group_ID")."<BR>";

} 

*/

?>
```

any Idea about issues?  its worked xampp Local side.But Not Working  Host server side ?

Comment: If you moved your code from test to live its likely that the location of the database and the userid and password have changed. Did you pick that up and make the changed to your connection request in PHP. As that message is basically saying you are tring to connect to somewhere that a MYSQL database does not exist

Comment: i have checked my connection with select query displaying data but my site code its showing error

Comment: If `the target machine actively refused it` then there is no MySQL or the Userid/password are incorrect, but most likely you are connecting to the wrong machine or using the wrong port number. **I notice that you do not test for errors** after your `mysql_connect()` **Start by doing that**

Comment: @RiggsFolly  sir i need to change my database connection code sir ?

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: _i need to change my database connection code_ Yes, so what can I do to help

Comment: changed and configure my server hosting code  still  i am getting error

Comment: I appreciate your frustration, but how can I know what your hosting service requires. I dont eneb know what hosting provider you are using.

Comment: var $host="my03.winhost.com";  i have using

Comment: Can you connect to the server at all? I find that, whenever I receive this kind of message, the service is dead and requires restarting.